# Each Firebase cloud functions takes it own time to start the processing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cold-start

I am having this total of 7 firebase cloud functions deployed, I know something called cold start time which firebase takes before starts processing any request. It can be minimized by reducing the dependencies and having lazy initialization etc. I am trying everything possible to reduce the cold start time.

But now the problem I am facing is, each cloud function takes its own cold start time on its first invocation.
Previously I thought that only the first invocation of first firebase function will take time to processing, but looks like it is not the case. Every function takes its own time.

Any idea on how to avoid the cold start for other functions also (except the first invocation) ? Like something can be done during deployment etc.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM) on minimizing cold start time.

Comment: I have already watched it and know the steps to minimize the cold start time but the problem is, it happens for each firebase function. How to avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a corn job that runs each 15 minutes to trigger the functions and keep them "warm", there are websites that offer free corn jobs.

if you are using triggers, the corn job should do actions that would activate the triggers

Comment: you mean trigger all the functions for every 15 minutes ? meaning I need to send 7 different requests to all 7 functions. I understand this, but is there any way to achieve that with just one request for every 15 minutes?

Comment: if they are 7 HTTP functions, you can expose them under the same endpoint and route with express the requests, you'll only send one request, and no there is no other solution, the cold start will always be there, other serverless providers have less cold start time if you want to further minimize the time.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the Cloud Functions being stateless, they're subject to what is known as a *cold start*. A cold start is just the execution environment being initialised from scratch.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#performance) you can find some tips and tricks on how to reduce cold starts, but unfortunately, they are unavoidable to a large extent, though they can be reduced if following best practices.